# How do you add thumbnail support for custom post types?

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

the thumbnail support is working for post, but I have another post type called product and it is not working for this. I am trying: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'product' ) );`
I am also using the multiple post thumbnail plugin.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By default all custom post adds support for Title and editor, if you want more stuff like comments, thumbnail and revisions you have to add it manually in the **support** argument.

Read more about how to register your custom post type [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), you can also find the section about **support** to see what you can add.

Here is an example wehere to register thumbnail for the custom post "Books" and it hav support for:  `'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments'`

```
function codex_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Books', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Book', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'book'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Book'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Book'),
    'new_item' => __('New Book'),
    'all_items' => __('All Books'),
    'view_item' => __('View Book'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Books'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No books found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No books found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('Books')

  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 
  register_post_type('book',$args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Comment: I was using post-thumbnail instead of thumbnail . It makes sense now . post-thumbnail adds thumbnail for the post but for custom post type one needs thumbnail

Comment: I have 'thumbnail' in my 'supports' array but I cannot save featured image in my custom post.

Comment: @esmitex: Besides the `supports` part you also have to have an`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails')` in an appropriate action or something (which the OP already had).

Answer (score 16):

For custom posts, you *first* have to enable support for thumbnails:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
function theme_setup() {
    register_post_type( 'yourposttype', array(
        ...,
        'supports' => array('title', ...,'thumbnail'),
    ));
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
```

Comment: Worked for me perfectly but can you please explain why "add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );" is necessary to add?

Comment: I'd have to read the source to be sure, but I suppose register_post_type only loads supporting code if the theme is set to support thumbnails.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `add_post_type_support()` to add a single feature, if you don't want to rewrite the default `supports` options when registering your custom post type:

```
add_post_type_support( 'product', 'thumbnail' );
```

Comment: This is the best answer by far. The use of `support` attribute breaks the block editor UI.